# Android 14 crashing while trying to read from device, with 128 error code

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-14

I have an app that works with BLE using https://github.com/Beepiz/BleGattCoroutines library and it is working fine but crashing while reading some characteristics from the device like

```kotlin
  val char = connection.getServiceCharacteristic(characteristic)!!
            connection.readCharacteristic(char).value!!

 private suspend fun GattConnection.getServiceCharacteristic(
        characteristic: String,
    ): BluetoothGattCharacteristic? {
        if (mockController.isMocksEnabled) {
            return BluetoothGattCharacteristic(characteristic.asUUID(), 0, 1)
        }
        val characteristicUUID = characteristic.asUUID()
        return discoverServices()
            .firstNotNullOfOrNull { service ->
                service.characteristics.firstOrNull { it.uuid == characteristicUUID }
            }
    }
```

> > [DefaultDispatcher-worker-8] - read error com.beepiz.bluetooth.gattcoroutines.OperationFailedException:
> > com.beepiz.bluetooth.gattcoroutines.OperationFailedException: status: 128
> > at com.beepiz.bluetooth.gattcoroutines.GattConnectionImpl.readCharacteristic(GattConnectionImpl.kt:491)
> > at com.beepiz.bluetooth.gattcoroutines.GattConnectionImpl$readCharacteristic$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
> > at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
> > at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

and problem is occuring only on Android 14 devices and all is working fine with others. Permissions also granted. What could be the case ?

Comment: While Android 14 is a year old, the library you are using was last committed 2 years ago. So it is most likely an incompatibility problem. At the very least, it is not wise to use an unmaintained library at all, so I would recommend using a better-maintained library.

Comment: The GATT API in Android is over ten years old and is backwards compatible. So a library that is only two years old should definitely not be "broken" just due to being two years old. In any case, you need to figure out at what step the error is being returned. You can also check the hci log in Wireshark to see what's wrong. Or use e.g. nRF Connect app to diagnose.

Comment: @Emil, that is not true. Android 14 for example [set MTU to 517](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#mtu-set-to-517) and depending on how your code handles such a change, this will be a problem.

Comment: Please post he full stack trace of the error. I would also recommend this for the issue you have created on github.com.

Comment: What happens if you try to read the same characteristic in e.g. nRF Connect?